# How can I use the width of an element in my computed property reactively

Tags: vue.js

I am attempting to set a computed property based on the width of an element in my component. The problem is that I do not know how to get the width in a way that is reactive.

I've got a ref on my element to get the width which works. However I can't seem to get vue to detect that the width is changing

I have the element set up as:

```
<div ref="myDiv"></div>
```

and my computed property as:

```
myProperty() {
  return this.$refs.myDiv.clientWidth/2;
}
```

myProperty evaluates correctly, but does not change as the width of myDiv changes

Comment: To answer properly you need to know what is changing your element size. And put watchers there

Comment: You could use `vue-resize` library - it provides a component whcih runs the hook when the size of the DOM element changes: https://github.com/Akryum/vue-resize

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to `resize` event

```
  data() {
   return {
     clientWidth: 0
    }
  },

  // bind event handlers to the `handleResize` method (defined below)
  mounted: function () {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
  },
  beforeDestroy: function () {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
  },

  methods: {
    // whenever the document is resized, re-set the 'clientWidth' variable
    handleResize (event) {
      if (this.$refs.myDiv) {
        this.clientWidth = this.$refs.myDiv.clientWidth
      }
    }
  }
```

then you can use `this.clientWidth` where you want to get clientWidth.

```
  myProperty() {
    return this.clientWidth/2;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option for future readers of this question is to use a simple mixin I created https://github.com/Circuit8/vue-computed-dimensions. It creates computed properties for the dimensions and position of any ref you like, as in the example here:

```js
<template>
  <div ref="wrapper">
    ...

    <div ref="other">...</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import computedDimensions from "vue-computed-dimensions";

export default {
  // computedDimensions accepts a list of refs to use.
  // each ref provided will produce 4 computed properties
  // in this example we will have wrapperWidth wrapperHeight wrapperX and wrapperY. As well as otherWidth, otherHeight, otherX, and otherY.
  // these can then be used in other computed properties to base reactivity on the rendered dimensions of an element
  mixins: [computedDimensions("wrapper", "other")],
};
</script>
```